# How to go to Batch Update via Profile in one click?

Tags: civicontribute, profile, developer

I have a weekly procedure where I need to batch update Pending Contributions. It requires several manual steps to finally get to Batch Update via profile form:

1. Go to Find Contributions
2. Check Pending / Click Search
3. Check all Contributions radio, in the resultset page
4. Select action "Batch Update..." from dropdown
5. Select profile to use

I know it's not that bad, but I was trying to find a way to add a Menu item, where clicking it opens Batch Update via Profile form, with the profile I want, for all Pending Contributions.

Still think a good/easy way to implement this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Luciano,  Unfortunately this can not be added as a menu item because you are working with a search result.

You could create a custom process that can be added to a menu.  Something like...create a custom contribution search (that filters by pending) with a hook that displays a profile that you can use to update.

If you need a consultant to do this for you, it is probably not worth it. Sorry....